# Tomcat keystore exception

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate, keystore

when I lunch this command: 
`sudo $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore .` 
into ubuntu terminal and after I compile the module for generate a keystore I receive this exception:

```
Errore keytool: java.io.FileNotFoundException: . (Is a directory)
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify keystore filename instead of '.'

Please refer to [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html) tutorial for more info on using keytool.